# SQL Server STWithin Spatial index does not work

Tags: sql-server, gis, spatial-query, spatial-index

1.Spatial index does not work(Query cost 10s)

```
SELECT geomFROM cj_pl_l WHERE geom.MakeValid ( ).STWithin (geometry :: STGeomFromText 
('POLYGON ((……))', 4547 ).MakeValid ()) =1
```

2.Spatial index work（Query cost 2s,I save above-mentioned polygon to temp table[testGeom]）

```
select b.* from  testGeom a,cj_pl_l b where b.geom.STWithin(a.geom)=1
```

If I want Condition1 the Spatial Index to work, how should I solve？

Thanks!

Comment: My first guess is that the `MakeVald()` call on the table side of the query is the culprit. Why is that necessary? Do you have invalid data in your table?

Comment: Due to the nature of spatial indexes they only support a limited number of predicate forms. Have you read the [Methods Supported by Spatial Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#methods) documentation yet?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I did,the STWhin method is supported.

Comment: @BenThul Because the sql run error.
`System.ArgumentException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.ThrowIfInvalid()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.STWithin(SqlGeometry other)`
When I use other table and don't use `MakeVald()` method，the sql not thorw error,but the Spatial Index also don't work.

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you have to continually run `MakeValid()` against the data in your table, you have invalid data. If suggest fixing the data (something like `update yourTable set yourColumn = yourColumn MakeValid()`.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is the first `MakeValid` in `geom.MakeValid ()`.

The index covers `geom` column, but `MakeValid` returns a new geometry value, which might be different and is not indexed, and thus SQL cannot use it.

Remove the first `MakeValid` call, preferably after making sure all the geometries in the table are valid. You generally don't want to fix stored geometries with `MakeValid` anywhere in the query path - it is slow and it prevents index usage.

That said, second `MakeValid`, on the constant geometry value, should be fine.

Comment: Thank you suggestion, I tried,you can see comment above.
When I use other spatial table and don't use `MakeVald()` method，but the Spatial Index also don't work.

Comment: Can you please update the question? It currently says in the second case the index works.